# Suppose $f$ is entire and one-to-one. Show that $f(z)=az+b$.

Tags: complex-analysis

My instinct is that it may be proved by Liouville's extended theorem. But how to do so? Or are there any other methods?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider the image of the unit circle. It has a winding number of 1.

Comment: If $f(z)$ is not $b + az$ then $f(z) = b + az + cz^2 + \cdots$.  And $z\mapsto z^2$ is not one-to-one.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I don't see how your hint leads to an easy solution. Could you expand?

Comment: @CalvinLin I don't see how that leads to a solution. Could you explain?

Comment: @Potato That's what I call team work.

Comment: @julien I only know how to solve this problem in the way I indicate below. I want to learn these other solutions!

Comment: @Potato See the duplicate for above for different  arguments.

Comment: Now that I think of it, certainly more work than that is needed.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Consider $f(\frac{1}{z})$ and examine the behavior of the singularity at $0$. It can't be an essential singularity (see this using the Weierstrass-Casorati theorem on the behavior near an essential singularity along with the open mapping theorem). So it is either removable or a pole. Then $f(\frac{1}{z})$ has a finite number of negative powers of $z^{-1}$ in its Laurent expansion, so $f(z)$ is a finite power series and must be a polynomial. If the polynomial has degree greater than $1$, then it has $2$ or more roots, contradicting the one-to-one hypothesis.

Note that this gives you the automorphism group of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: There are 2 or more roots...but what if the roots are in the same location, so that we have one distinct root with multiplicity = n?  Doesn't this keep f as a one-to-one function, @Potato?

Comment: @LebronJames If it has a root with multiplicity $2$, then locally at that root it looks like $w=z^2$, which is clearly not injective. Ahlfors provides a rigorous explanation of this somewhere his book. Essentially, WLOG we may assume the root is at zero, so $f(z)=z^2(1+\dots)$, and then you can take a square root locally since the second factor is nonzero around $0$.

Comment: Awesome stuff, @Potato.  I saw this in the summer - what a timely reminder from you :)  Thanks so much.  Have a great night.

Comment: @LebronJames My pleasure. Good luck with your studies.